# TomEE - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/application/ResourceHandlerWrapper

Tags: myfaces, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I can't start my server in Eclipse (Neon).
The server is TomEE 7.0.2 Plus. I configured it as Tomcat 8.5

When I start the server I get the following error.

```
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:42 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMATION: Server version:        Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/8.5.6 (7.0.2)
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:42 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMATION: Server built:          Oct 6 2016 20:15:31 UTC
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:42 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMATION: Server number:         8.5.6.0
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:42 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMATION: OS Name:               Windows 7
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:42 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMATION: OS Version:            6.1
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:42 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMATION: Architecture:          amd64
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:42 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMATION: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:42 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMATION: JVM Version:           1.8.0_60-b27
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:42 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMATION: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:42 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMATION: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\data\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:42 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMATION: CATALINA_HOME:         D:\Programme\TomEE Plus
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:42 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\data\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:42 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\Programme\TomEE Plus
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:42 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\data\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:42 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\Programme\TomEE Plus\endorsed
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:42 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:42 AM sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMATION: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CheckPoint\Endpoint Security\Endpoint Common\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Siemens\System;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\hansma4\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse neon;;.
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:42 AM sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:42 AM sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMATION: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:42 AM sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:42 AM sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMATION: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog info
INFORMATION: Using 'openejb.jdbc.datasource-creator=org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator'
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFORMATION: ********************************************************************************
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFORMATION: OpenEJB http://tomee.apache.org/
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFORMATION: Startup: Thu Oct 26 11:08:43 CEST 2017
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFORMATION: Copyright 1999-2016 (C) Apache OpenEJB Project, All Rights Reserved.
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFORMATION: Version: 7.0.2
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFORMATION: Build date: 20161106
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFORMATION: Build time: 07:23
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFORMATION: ********************************************************************************
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFORMATION: openejb.home = D:\Programme\TomEE Plus
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFORMATION: openejb.base = C:\data\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initializeOWB
INFORMATION: Created new singletonService org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@65d6b83b
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initializeOWB
INFORMATION: Succeeded in installing singleton service
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigUtils searchForConfiguration
INFORMATION: Cannot find the configuration file [conf/openejb.xml].  Creating one at C:\data\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\conf\openejb.xml
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory init
INFORMATION: TomEE configuration file is 'C:\data\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\conf\openejb.xml'
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFORMATION: Configuring Service(id=Tomcat Security Service, type=SecurityService, provider-id=Tomcat Security Service)
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFORMATION: Configuring Service(id=Default Transaction Manager, type=TransactionManager, provider-id=Default Transaction Manager)
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFORMATION: Configuring Service(id=My DataSource, type=Resource, provider-id=Default JDBC Database)
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFORMATION: Configuring Service(id=My Unmanaged DataSource, type=Resource, provider-id=Default JDBC Database)
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFORMATION: Configuring Service(id=My Singleton Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Singleton Container)
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFORMATION: Configuring Service(id=My Stateful Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Stateful Container)
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFORMATION: Configuring Service(id=My Stateless Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Stateless Container)
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentsResolver loadFrom
WARNUNG: File error: <Deployments dir="apps/"> - Does not exist: C:\data\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\apps
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog info
INFORMATION: Using 'openejb.deployments.classpath=false'
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFORMATION: Creating TransactionManager(id=Default Transaction Manager)
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFORMATION: Creating SecurityService(id=Tomcat Security Service)
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:43 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFORMATION: Creating Resource(id=My DataSource)
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/application/ResourceHandlerWrapper
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1204)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomEEWebappClassLoader.java:204)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.ClassUtils.classForName(ClassUtils.java:187)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.ClassUtils.simpleClassForName(ClassUtils.java:213)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.ClassUtils.buildApplicationObject(ClassUtils.java:547)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.ClassUtils.buildApplicationObject(ClassUtils.java:519)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configureApplication(FacesConfigurator.java:733)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:595)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.buildConfiguration(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:416)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:73)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 37 more

Okt 26, 2017 11:08:50 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
SCHWERWIEGEND: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Okt 26, 2017 11:08:50 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
SCHWERWIEGEND: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
```

The server is empty and if I add an application, I just get the NoClassDefFoundError two times. Does anyone know how to solve this problem.
If anything is missing please let me know.

Comment: Important advice: Upgrade your setup to use TomEE 7.0.4, as this resolves several issues with security problems found since Tomcat 8.5.6 (see your log output in the question). TomEE 7.0.4 is now built upon 8.5.20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved my problem. I had a jar in my `%Java_Home%\jre\lib\ext\` folder. This jar destroyed my `ResourceHandlerWrapper`.
After removing the jar my server could start up normally.